# Codeigniter 3 - Problems Loading Dynamic Data from Model to Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Okay. So I have been stumping myself on where I have gone wrong with this. I am not-so-new to PHP but I am also no expert, although I am getting more and more used to OOP. I have recently got into CodeIgniter 3. I like it, I use it, it's pretty simple to grasp in the beginning.

However, I am in the learning stage where I cannot successfully pass dynamic data, from the database into the controller using a Model.

And just as an FYI: I am using `MY_Controller` as my Base Controller, and have set a $data object to pass variables application wide. I know my problem is not due to the use of `MY_Controller`, because when I use static `$this->data['KEY'] = 'VALUE';` or `$this->data array('KEY' => 'VALUE');`, my variables get passed into my views. So `MY_Controller` is functional.

My problem resides in creating a `Settings_model`. Its sole purpose is to take data from a database table `settings` and extrapolate certain columns of data, such a/an: application title, background color, etc.

So. On to my question/s, and what I have tried to do to fix this.

First, here is my `MY_Controller`:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();


        $this->data = array(

            'app_title'             =>  $this->settings_model->get_title('$title'),
            'meta_author'           =>  APP_AUTHOR

        );

    }

}
```

And here is my Settings_model:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $title = '';

    public function __construct() {

        $this->load->database();

    }


    public function get_title($title) {

      $this->db->select('app_title');
      $this->db->from->('settings');
      $this->db-where('app_title', $title);

      return $this->db->get()->row('app_title');



    }


}
```

**My Problem**
When using the sytnax above. i am able to see my applications output in the browser. Everything is rendered properly, all the static variables I've assigned in `MY_Controller` work. Everything is good ... except, the `$app_title` variable (which is in my views, and assigned in `MY_Controller`) does not load the data from the database, as the model instructed. As well as does not produce any error, warning or notice.

**What I've tried**
Man i tell you I have tried everything. i have tried inserting the query into MY_Controller directly and not using a Model (which I know is not proper MVC, but I wanted to try), like so:

**MY_Controller Using Straigh Query, no model**

```
        $this->data = array(

            'app_title'             =>  $this->db->query('GET app_title FROM settings'),
            'meta_author'           =>  APP_AUTHOR

        );
```

And the one time i got somewhere, error/notice wise was when i altered the `Settings_Model`, like so:

**Altered Settings Model**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $title = '';

    public function __construct() {

        $this->load->database();

    }


    public function get_title($title) {

      $this->db->select('app_title');
      $this->db->from->('settings');
      $this->db-where('app_title', $title);

      // Before it was this:
      return $this->db->get->row('app-title');

      // But I changed it to this
      return $this->db->get()->row()->app_title;



    }


}
```

But that syntax above gave me the error in this Image of a non Object Error

[image]

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

**Now the question/s**

1. Why when i use the first approach of the settings_model, using `return $this->db->get()->row('app_title');` does it show all of my applications output in the browser, but everywhere the `$app_title` variable is called, it itself displays no value from the database, via MY_Controller and Settings_model?
2. Why when i use the second approach of the settings_model, using `return $this->db->get()->row()->app_title;` does it produce the `Trying to get property of Non Object` error in the image i linked to above?
3. What on earth am I doing wrong? I know I am still on the early learning stages of OOP, and Models, etc. But I must be missing something, I know something is not right.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated and welcomed. I thank everyone for their input.

EDIT 1: Thanks to @Mirceac21 for asking. I am `autoloading` the `settings_model` in `config/autoload.php`.

EDIT 2: I have now switched the `var $data` to `public $data` in `MY_Controller` as @Mirceac21 suggested. Still the same error but he is correct about not using `var` there.

Comment: Where do you load (in controller) the settings_model?

Comment: @Mirceac21 It is autoloaded in config/autoload.php

Comment: In ```MY_Controller``` you have ```var $data```. Class properties shouln't have ```var``` keywords, they can be ```public```, ```protected``` or ```private```

Comment: @Mirceac21 okay so I have switched it  between all 3, 'protected', 'public' (being the most obvious) and 'private'. All produce the same error of a non object.

Comment: In your case should be public because you want to access this variable in controller. If you make it protected/public you have to create a getter method. Try with public.

Comment: @Mirceac21 I switched it to `public`. And edited my question to reflect it as well as give you credit.

Comment: In ```MY_Controller``` you have ```'app_title' =>  $this->settings_model->get_title('$title')```. Where the ```$title``` variable is coming from? And you should remove the quotes ```'app_title' =>  $this->settings_model->get_title($title)```.

Comment: @Mirceac21 I've tried to remove the quotes, but then of course it gives me an `Undefined variable: title` in `MY_Controller`. I think this is where my issue is, it's not recognizing the `$title` variable. This is why I can't get the reault. I thought adding `$title` as an argument to the `get_title` method, it would pull `$title` from the model.

Comment: In ```Settings_model``` on this line ```$this->db-where('app_title', $title);``` what ```$title``` should be?

Comment: @Mirceac21 that's what confuses me. I thought that `$title` was coming from the `get_title ($title)` and that is what assigned it. Especially declaring `public $title` above the constructor funxtion. This is where I'm getting lost on how this works. As I said, I'm new to OOP and Models loading dynamic data.Even if I take `$title` out of both the model and controller, it still produces the non object error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out. With the help of @Mirceac21. I change the `var $data` to `public $data` in `MY_Controller`.

Then in the `Settings_model`, I took out the `WHERE` clause and it worked. Here is the new working code below:

**MY_Controller**

```html
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
 // $data object used for $this->data
    public $data;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        /*
         * The $data array('KEY' => 'VALUE') variable sets are used
         * in other Controller Classes that extend MY_Controller.
         */

        $this->data = array(

            'app_title'             =>  $this->settings_model->get_title('$title'),
            'meta_author'           =>  APP_AUTHOR

        );

    }

}
```

Then in the `Settings_model` I made the following changes, remove `->where('app-title', $title);`. Like so:

```html
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $title = '';

    public function __construct() {

        $this->load->database();

    }


    public function get_title($title) {

      $this->db->select('app_title');
      $this->db->from->('settings');
      
   // I removed the following where->(); and it now loads the dynamic data
   // $this->db-where('app_title', $title);

      return $this->db->get()->row('app_title');



    }


}
```

Now everything works as planned. I knew it was something simple and stupid 9for lack of better words). Thank you to @Mirceac21 for your input.